# How to make a field validate if it's not empty

Tags: php, forms, validation

I what to validate a field so it will throw an error if its value empty or the length is less than or equal to 10.
But it only validates when its empty if the length is 1 or more it submits the value.

Need Help here to make it validate

```
if (empty($_POST["comment"]) && $_POST["comment"] <= 10) {
    $comment_err = "Please send a message more than 10 characters";
}
else {
    $comment = sanitize($_POST["comment"]);
}
```

Comment: you're looking for [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php).

Comment: it cannot be empty *AND* have a length (<=10) use *OR* instead

Comment: ^ I thought of that also but they beat me to it.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yes but in this case it will change the logic. if empty, OP wants to set the error message

Comment: @olibiaz You are totally correct, my bad.

Comment: they still need to use `strlen()` here.

Comment: see all answers below, they'll all work for you :-)

Comment: @executable about your suggestive edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21170442 - that last part in the title should remain, I feel.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is *not clear and precise*, but I think what you're looking for if :

- Throw an error **if variable is empty**
- Throw an error **if variable length is less than 10**

So use *`OR` ( || )* in your *if* statement, and `strlen()` to get variable length (*as outlined in comment by Funk Forty Niner*):

```
if(empty($_POST["comment"]) || strlen($_POST["comment"]) <= 10){
   $comment_err = "Please send a message more than 10 characters";
}
else{
   $comment = sanitize($_POST["comment"]);
}
```

Comment: *"as outlined in comments (by `{optional}`)..."* ;-)

Comment: You’re welcome, don’t forget to mark one of the answers as « answer »

Answer (score 1):

Just check the length. If it's greater than 10 length, then it's definitely not empty, so you don't need to check for that explicitly.

```
if(isset($_POST["comment"]) && strlen($_POST["comment"]) > 10){
```

`isset` is just there to prevent an undefined index warning if that comment key doesn't exist.

(This reverses your if and else blocks, by the way, because it checks for good data instead of the error condition.)

<sub>This was [partially answered in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52876675/how-to-make-a-field-validate-if-its-not-empty-or-more-than-10-in-php#comment92666903_52876675), but Funk Forty Niner is such a generous soul that he gives away his wisdom for free with no expectation of fake internet points, all he asks for in return is some r e s p e c t when he comes home.</sub>

Comment: [*wink...*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52876675/how-to-make-a-field-validate-if-its-not-empty-or-more-than-10-in-php#comment92667394_52876973).

Comment: Don't play that song guys.

Comment: @Progrock why, does it get stuck in your head too?

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your code:

1. first your condition is not correct, you cannot have at the same time an empty index and checking his size. So you should have `empty($_POST["comment"]) || $_POST["comment"] <= 10`
2. you also cannot check the length of a string by checking the value against an integer, as @Funk Forty Niner told in comments, you have to use  `strlen()` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

so your final code will be:

```
if(empty($_POST["comment"]) || strlen($_POST["comment"]) <= 10){
 $comment_err = "Please send a message more than 10 characters";
}
else{
 $comment = sanitize($_POST["comment"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanx bros i appreciate